# Adding CLR UDF to SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sqlclr, database-project

I've created a new database project to group together all my useful stored procedures and functions so they can be easily deployed to any of my servers.

I'd like to add a couple of CLR UDFs.  I tried adding a CLR project to my solution but this wants to be given a specific database to deploy to which is in conflict with the rest of the solution as the point is I want to be able to deploy anywhere!

Am i missing something?!

Sam : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was this...

- Create a SQL Server 2005/2008 Database Project (inluding a new solution)
- Add a SQL CLR database project to the solution but click cancel when it asks for a database
- Add a reference to your CLR project from your main database project
- Uncheck the deployment option on the CLR project

That was it, now when I deploy my database project it includes the CLR functions wherever I choose to deploy it.

Luckily some guy had documented the whole process so go check it out [here](http://www.aaronlowe.net/archive/2010/08/database-project-with-clr-project-dependency/)

Comment: Hi Sam. The link you have given is broken. Can you find it?

Answer (score 0):

We added a normal class library to our solution, containing a class with static methods for our UDFs.

eg:

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]   
public static bool MyMethod(string x)
{
    ...
}
```

Then add a reference to this project from the database project.

Comment: I've added a normal class library (with clr udf) to my solution and referenced it from the db project, it builds both projects but only deploys one of them, is there something else I need to do to hook them together?!

Comment: Have you added the DLL to your database project - Schema Objects\Database Level Objects\Assemblies\yourdll.dll? This should allow it to be deployed as part of the database project.

Comment: Cheers Matt, yeh, i had the referencing set up but Visual Studio refused to hook the 2 together complaining of a mismatching signature even though the whole team had double checked it. I ended up finding another solution, thanks for your help : )